# taking uncommitted changes on the wrong branch to the right branch

Tags: mercurial

I am using Mercurial.

I have some uncommitted changes but I am on the wrong branch, how do I update to the right branch and take the changes with me?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For uncommited changes you can use the [Shelve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension):

1. `hg shelve --all`
2. `hg up correct_branch_name`
3. `hg unshelve`

Comment: My hg version (3.7.3) doesn't seem to  use the `--all` flag. Simply calling `hg shelve` shelves everything.

Answer (score 12):

I asked on irc

mpm said

```
hg diff > mychanges; hg up -C somewhere; hg import --no-commit mychanges
```

which I had considered but is what I was trying to avoid.

d70 said

```
i think you can easily do it by "hg update"ing to a changeset that is a
parent of the branch you're trying to switch to, and then "hg update"ing to the
tip of that branch
```

so I did that.

```
hg up -r <shared root rev>
hg up branchIwant
```

I asked about "why" and was told "you are not allowed to update across branches" which didn't make sense to me at first. Then I realized that because I went through the shared root rev, it isn't across branches.

Comment: Cool! Thank you a lot! It's the most simple way to commit my changes to another already existing branch:)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use

```
hg qnew
hg qpop
hg up -c <target-rev>
hg qpush
hg qfinish qtip
```

But I also use jrwren’s approach of going through an ancestor quite regularly.